# IntelliJ Cannot Copy Error

Tags: intellij-idea

I am having an issue with IntelliJ, where it presents a modal popup saying

```
Error

Canot copy sourcedir/somejar to destination/somejar. Reason sourcedir/somejar (No such file or directory)
```

However when I do a ls sourcedir/somejar, I can find it.

Answer (score 0):

[Cleaning your IntelliJ system cache](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cleaning-system-cache.html) may solve your problem.

Go to File -> Invalidate Caches...

Then click Invalidate and Restart.

From their website:

> "...the only way to solve some conflicts is to clean out the cache..."
>
> *Cleaning out the system caches causes a complete rebuild of all the projects ever run in the current version of IntelliJ IDEA.*